# Dynamically configure spring boot h2 database

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I want to dynamically configure the H2 database that comes with my spring boot application. All the examples I have seen talk about adding or changing the `application.properties` file.

What I want to do is something like this which is executed at boot time (hence **dynamically**):

```
// pseudo code
if environment variable or argument defined (ex: --h2.location = /tmp.foo.txt)
{
  define url spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:<h2.location>
  keep all other default values
}
else
{
  use default spring.datasource.url (memory)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get that dynamically calculated at boot time with a single line in the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=${h2.file.datasource:jdbc:h2:mem:testdb}
```

Where your argument variable would be the datasource url: `h2.file.datasource=jdbc:h2:file:./tmp.foo.txt`

---

If you want more control of the datasource creation just write a configuration component with a method that returns a datasource:

```
@Configuration
public class H2DatasurceConfiguration {

    @Value("${h2.location:#{null}}")
    private String h2Location;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();

        if (h2Location != null) {
            dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:file:" + h2Location);
            // Additional datasource configuration for file db
        } else {
            dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
            // Additional datasource configuration for in memmory db
        }
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was definitely looking more at the fully dynamic (code) version like your second example. After experimentation, it looks like you can also use a `fun dataSourceProperties(): DataSourceProperties` as long as it is marked with `@Bean` and `@Primary`. The advantage is that it gets populated by properties from the `application.properties` file and you can override whichever you want.